# Why does Google Identity Platform REST API not recognize my (Firebase) Provider API Key?

Tags: firebase, rest, google-cloud-platform, google-identity

I have setup GCP's Identity Platform with the "Email / Password" Provider. I have created a User record for test purposes and was able to sign in with this user.

I am now trying to sign in with the same user through the Identity Platform REST API. As per [instructions in the API documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/use-rest-api#before_you_begin), I have obtained an API key from the Identity Providers page (in Google Cloud Console).

My HTTP request looks like this:

```
curl 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=[API_KEY]' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-binary '{"email":"[EMAIL_ADDRESS]","password":"[PASSWORD]","returnSecureToken":true}'
```

Note: `[..]` denotes a placeholder for sensitive content.

The response from this request comes back as this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "API_KEY_INVALID",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "service": "identitytoolkit.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Why is my API key from the "Identity Providers" page not recognized by the REST API?**

The "Identity Providers" page also shows an `authDomain` value in the form: `[GOOGLE_PROJECT_NAME].firebaseapp.com`. Do I need to incorporate this into my API request? How?

**UPDATE:** I logged into the Firebase Console website and created a new web application. The app now has its own API key and the same API key now appears in my Identity Providers page and when I use it in my REST API call, it works.

My question now is - What is the relationship between the Firebase web app and my Identity Platform instance? I've not seen this "step" documented anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your Firebase project, which is connected to your Identity Platform instance, is the source of the Firebase web app. Between the two services, a bridge is built by the Firebase project. You can use the API key created for your Firebase project to authenticate API queries made on behalf of your Firebase web app to the Identity Platform REST API.

Comment: Thanks. As I've written in my question, I was not able to use the Firebase project API key initially. Only after I created a web app in the Firebase project did the API key change and I was able to use it. My questions is - Is this normal? Why is this not documented?